# Add a class to the parent li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add an "active" class to an li when clicked.  The "active" class should also be present even when you click on a sub-page of that li.

For example:

```
<ul class="primarynav">
    <li id="first">
        <a href="#" id="link1" class="">link1</a>
        <ul class="megamenu" id="">
            <li class="column"><h4 class="special"><a href="#">sub-link</a</h4></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="second">link2</li>
    <li id="third"><a href="#" id="link3" class="">link3</a>
        <ul class="megamenu" id="">
            <li class="column"><h4 class="special"><a href="#">sub-link3</a></h4></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

perhaps something like this

```
$('.primarynav a').click(function() {
    // remove other links with 'active' class
    $('.primarynav a').removeClass('active');
    // set new 'active' link
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think this makes more sense than my overly wordy answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target **all the children**, you can use the `.children()` method without any selector. This should work regardless of the complexity of the elements below the first `<li>`.

```
$("#primarynav li").children().click(function() {(this.addClass("active"))};
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/

---

### Update

Take a look at this code below. It's also in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rRkeJ/3/
It's basically the same idea as above but adapted more to what I think you want

```
$(".primarynav li").children().click(function() {
    $(".primarynav").children().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent(".activable").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  I need something similar to http://www.target.com/.  You'll notice when you hover over "Men" then click on "Active Wear" the parent "Men" LI is active (has grey background).  My menu isn't that complex has targets, but I just need to have an active class when a user clicks on the parent LI and also if the user clicks on on a child of that parent LI, the parent LI needs to have an active class.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is a completely different situation. I think it's not just a bunch of `li`s, but `iframe`s that basically, with every click, load most of the page with new html based on an ajax call.

Comment: I tried..


`$(document).ready(function(){
          var str=location.href.toLowerCase(); 
        $('ul.primarynav li a').each(function() {
                if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        $(this).attr("class","active"); //hightlight parent tab
                     }  
                });
      });  `


Not sure how to modify so when a user clicks on child element the active class still stays on the parent.

Comment: @user check out the updated response regarding to change the parent `li`.